# Windows 10: Turn on UPS beeping

Tags: windows-10, battery, ups

[Windows 10 Pro x64, v 1709, APC Back-UPS 550]

I am using the OS-native battery control for power management.  I seem to be having the opposite problem of everyone else on the interwebs: my UPS did **not** start beeping when the power recently went out, and I had to scamper to shut everything down cleanly when I finally realized I had 3 minutes of battery left. I am not seeing any option to turn on the UPS beep when the power goes out - does that exist in Windows 10, or am I going to need to install the APC-specific software that came with with UPS?

Comment: Where did all the comments go? There were several that were relevant and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the APC Back-UPS 550 on my machine at work right now (specific model is BE550G) and I have the PowerChute Personal Edition installed.  By default it should beep, but the only way to change whether it beeps or not is through the PowerChute software:

[image]

Once you have configured the battery backup alarms, you can uninstall PowerChute and the UPS will remember the last setting it had.

Note that the settings in the pic are for the UPS itself to beep, not anything from Windows.  With PowerChute installed, there are options for the software to make noises under **Configuration** > **Options**.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping I wouldn't have to go thru the hassle of installing/uninstalling it - guess I will bite the bullet...

Comment: I have a similar model (might be the same) at home for my router and modem.  It beeped by default, but in order to make it not beep, I had to install the UPS and software on my PC, change the setting, then I could move it back to the network equipment w/o the beeps.